# What is the purpose of lines which start with double colon in TCL?

Tags: tcl

Some of [Cisco](http://www.cisco.com/) routers run operating system called IOS which has a built in TCL interpreter. I studied an example script for IOS TCL and it had following line at the beginning of the script:

```
::cisco::eem::event_register_timer cron name crontimer2 cron_entry $_cron_entry maxrun_sec 240
```

This `$_cron_entry` variable is an environment variable with value `0-59/2 0-23/1 * * 0-7`, i.e. the line with double colon at the beginning can also be written like this:

```
::cisco::eem::event_register_timer cron name crontimer2 cron_entry 0-59/2 0-23/1 * * 0-7 maxrun_sec 240
```

Does the `0-59/2 0-23/1 * * 0-7` mean that execute `maxrun_sec 240` every other minute in every hour? If yes, then what is the `maxrun_sec` as it is not defined anywhere in the script itself. How to understand the `::cisco::eem::event_register_timer cron name crontimer2 cron_entry` part?

Comment: The line begins with a command: `::cisco::eem::event_register_timer` and that command takes arguments or parameters, which are supplied by placing them after the command name. If you want to know what the line means, you will have to understand the command first and what arguments it accepts.

Comment: The double colons are namespace separators. The two lines you show are **not** equivalent, since the variable's value is one word in the first invocation but five words in the second. `maxrun_sec` may possibly be a symbol only `event_register_timer` understands.

Comment: @Jerry, @Peter Lewerin Thanks! So basically `::cisco::eem::event_register_timer` is a command named `event_register_timer` which is inside the namespace(collection of commands and variables) `eem` and namespace `eem` is inside the namespace `cisco`? And now this command `event_register_timer` has 7 arguments "cron", "name", "crontimer2", "cron_entry", "0-59/2 0-23/1 * * 0-7", "maxrun_sec" and "240"?

Comment: @Martin That summarizes things pretty well I think, yup! :)

Comment: @Jerry Thanks for confirming this! One last thing- where are those namespaces (usually) stored? Are they built into TCL interpreter binary and loaded when requested in script, i.e. Cisco added some proprietary namespaces to its custom TCL interpreter?

Comment: @Martin I cannot say for sure, but usually those kinds of commands come either in the form of binaries or other scripts that create packages or modules. These are usually in the lib folder. If you have `package require cisco` somewhere in your script, you could run `package ifneeded cisco [package require cisco]` in the interpreter and this will return (among other things) the path from which the package is being sourced from.

Answer (score 5):

Those are command calls where those commands are given in fully-qualified form. The double-colon (`::`) is a *namespace separator*, and by analogy with the filesystem, if the name starts with the separator, it's resolved with respect to the global namespace.

For example, the global `set` command can *equivalently* be called as `::set`. It will work identically. This is useful if you're in another namespace that defines its own `set` command:

```
namespace eval example {
    proc set {} {
        for {::set x 1} {$x <= 5} {incr i} {
            puts "This is example::set with x = $x"
        }
    }

    set
}
```

Now, in your case the command is called `::cisco::eem::event_register_timer` in fully qualified form. That should be read as the `event_register_timer` command in the `eem` namespace that itself is in the `cisco` namespace, which in turn is a direct child of the global namespace. It's just like with filenames, except it's a multi-character separator.

(As for what it does… check the Cisco documentation. It's not a standard Tcl command…)